# Algorithm to sum a triple?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

We have an array A with m positive integer numbers, what's an algorithm that will

return true if there's a triple (x,y,z) in A
such that A[x] + A[y] + A[z] = 200

Otherwise return false. Numbers in array are distinct and running time must be O(n).

I came up with O(n^3). Any ideas on how to achieve this with O(n)?

Comment: is the value 200 constant?

Comment: Actually, since elements are distinct, assuming 200 is constant - your algorithm is `O(1)`, because number of elements in the array is bounded by 200.

Comment: @amit Why is that? The array could have billions of different numbers that are all larger than 200.

Comment: @tobias_k so filter them out and then do the O(200^3)=O(1) algorithm, I was assuming there are no redundant elements (so elements are in range [1,200]. If it's not the case, it's simple enough to transform it into ti.

Comment: Yes 200 constant. The array can be of any size and can hold any positive number.. we just want to find 3 numbers that when we add them up = 200

Comment: @amit Right, assuming that n >> 200, but that would still be O(n) for finding the numbers that are <200, not O(1). But I would assume that the algorithm should also be "O(n)" if there are just, say, 5 elements in the array.

Comment: @33ted Do you understand the observation of "you don't care about elements larger than 200, and there are at most 200 elements that are not larger than 200"?

Comment: yes i do. so this will have 2 loops.. 1st for filtering and 2nd for checking triples ?

Comment: You can make the triplet-checking part faster than n^3 (or 200^3) if you put all the numbers < 200 into a hashset; then whenever you have two numbers you can check whether the "missing" number is in the set in O(1), making it O(n^2) (or O(200^2)) in total.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since elements are unique, this boils down to pre processing the array in O(n) to filter redundant elements - which are larger than 200 (none of them will be in the triplet).

Than, you have an array which its size is no larger than 200.

Checking all triplets in this array is `O(200^3)=O(1)` (it can be done more efficiently in terms of constants though).

So, this will be `O(n) U O(200^3) = O(n)`

Comment: The filtered out numbers should be greater than or equal to 200 since they are positive integers

Comment: @cricket_007 Technically, yes, you also won't need 199,198 but those are optimization that are insignificant in terms of big O notation (and if any, I'd optimize the last part or finding triplets from those 200 elements)

Comment: He can also avoid `^3` and go for `^2` since if he puts all the numbers into a set he can quickly see if the required number aftering A+B to reach 200 is also in the set.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this problem with bit operation. Such as bitset in C++ STL.

Using 3 bitsets, the first bitset cache all numbers you can get it by add 1 number, the second bitset cache all numbers you can get it by add 2 numbers, the third bitset cache all numbers you can get it by add 3 numbers. Then if a new number is coming, you can maintain the bitsets by simple bit operation.

Here is a sample C++ code:

```
bitset<256> bs[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    bs[i].reset();

int N, number;

cin >> N;
while (N--)
{
    cin >> number;

    bs[3] |= (bs[2] << number);
    bs[2] |= (bs[1] << number);
    if (number <= 200)
        bs[1].set(number);

    //cout << "1: " << bs[1] << endl;
    //cout << "2: " << bs[2] << endl;
    //cout << "3: " << bs[3] << endl;
}

cout << bs[3][200] << endl;
```

The algorithm complexity is O(n). Because bit operation is quickly, each 64-bit long type can cache 64 number, so if you don't want to use bitset, you can use 4 long type(64 * 4 = 256) to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @amit's solution, but there is an question: How can we make it better, in our case just faster.

Here is my solution and it's almost based on amit' idea, but the asymptotic complexity == `O(n + sum*(sum+1)/2)`, where `n` is a length of input array.

Firstly, we need `n` steps to filter the input array and put each value, that less the sum into the new array, where index of the value is equal to the value. At the end of this step we have the array, which size is equal to sum and we are able to access any value in `O(1)`.

Finally, to find `x,y,z` we only need `sum*(sum+1)/2` steps.

```
typedef struct SumATripleResult
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;
} SumATripleResult;

SumATripleResult sumATriple(unsigned int totalSum, unsigned int *inputArray, unsigned int n)
{
    SumATripleResult result;

    unsigned int array[totalSum];

    //Filter the input array and put each value into 'array' where array[value] = value
    for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        unsigned int value = inputArray[i];

        if(value<totalSum)
        {
            array[value] = value;
        }
    }

    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;

    for (size_t i = 0; i<totalSum; i++)
    {
        x = array[i];

        for (size_t j = i+1; x>0 && j<totalSum; j++)
        {
            y = array[j];

            if( y==0 || x + y >= totalSum) continue;

            unsigned int zIdx = totalSum - (x + y);

            if(zIdx == x || zIdx == y) continue;

            z = array[zIdx];

            if( z != 0)
            {
                result.x = x;
                result.y = y;
                result.z = z;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    //nothing found
    return result;
}

//Test
unsigned int array[] = {1, 21, 30, 12, 15, 10, 3, 5, 6, 11, 17, 31};

SumATripleResult r = sumATriple(52, array, 12);
printf("result = %d %d %d", r.x, r.y, r.y);

r = sumATriple(49, array, 12);
printf("result = %d %d %d", r.x, r.y, r.y);

r = sumATriple(32, array, 12);
printf("result = %d %d %d", r.x, r.y, r.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as 3SUM problem and has no linear solution yet. I am providing a pseudo code running with O(n^2) using binary search algorithm:

```
sumTriple(А[1...n]: array of integers,sum: integer): bool

 sort(A)

 for i ← 1 to n-2
  j ← i+1
  k ← n

  while k > j
   if A[i]+A[j]+A[k] = sum
    print i,j,k
    return true

   else if A[i]+A[j]+A[k] > sum
    k ← k-1

   else // A[i]+A[j]+A[k] < sum
    j ← j+1

return false
```

More information and further details for the problem you can find [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)

Comment: You are neglecting an important fact that the SUM is bounded to 200 and elements are unique. With this observation, there is linear time algorithm.

Comment: The numbers according to him are not unique : "Numbers in array are distinct".

Comment: Yea, each number does not repeat twice. (Even without this assumption it can be done in linear time when the sum is constant, but that'll be slightly more complex - just make sure you don't add each element more than 3 times. It is easy to do with a counter array of size 200)